# Why change detection is not triggered when clicking on the checkbox?

Tags: angular

Until now I was convinced that, by default, every UI interaction events would trigger change detection in Angular (eg mouse click). However to my surprise, here

```
<input #checkbox type="checkbox" />
Value:{{checkbox.checked}} 
<button (click)="checkbox.checked=!checkbox.checked">Toggle</button>
```

clicking checkbox will not cause view to be updated but clicking on the button will.

So the question is, is change detection triggered by ANY browser events or only those that are bound to some angular logic. Did that change at some point?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-cwlsqf?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @PavelGatnar What he means is that clicking the checkbox itself will not update the text.

Comment: Not working on current FF and Chrome. Ty for checking @PavelGatnar

Comment: @Silvermind since it can be misleading, Iv clarified that I ment clicking the checkbox. Thanks

Comment: I suspect Angular is not monitoring every control, because it could be added to the DOM in another non-Angular way. The `click` event is parsed and managed, because it is known at 'compile' time, so the logic can be intercepted there. AFAIK Angular proxies all fields in your code to catch a change and notifies that an update to the UI has to be made. Using `ngModel` will work, because it is behaviour that can be compiled in. I think the html element is not considered reliable enough to use in the differ hook. This is a guess. I'm not an Angular insider :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `(click)="null"` into the input - it's the smallest (non-empty, because that isn't acceptable to the compiler) thing I could find that binds an event on to the checkbox.

Personally, I think that putting a checkbox in an angular template and giving it a reference variable should be enough to bind the checkbox into the change detection loop - but I guess it isn't... I have added an issue to the angular issues list: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/51061

Answer (score 0):

The change detection is only triggered if you change a varaible in the ts file.
You can try something like this:

ts:

```
   value = false;
```

html:

```
<input #checkbox type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

For the output you can use the checkbox.checked or the variable value.

Comment: Why would I - button works already. This is not an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Change detection is controlled via zone.js in angular. Zone.js is monitoring for every async event. Change detection is triggered when there's an async event is registered as you can see in checkbox it's not emitting any event but on the other hand button is emitting one.

So that's why change detection is triggered only in button's case not in checkbox's case

Comment: But there are native onClick events both on the checkbox and button itself right?

Comment: yes there's but they're not binded, hence not tracked by angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input #checkbox type="checkbox" (click)="this.checked" />
Value:{{checkbox.checked}} 
<button (click)="checkbox.checked=!checkbox.checked">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: How that answers my question?